# Convert csv to list of dictionaries of array

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a `csv` file which is in the format

```
id1, atr1, atr2.... atrn
id2, atr2_1,atr2_2....atr2_n
.
.
idn, atrn_1,atrn_2....atrn_n
```

I need to convert it to `list(dict(array))`, for example

```
'id1': array([atr1, atr2.... atrn]),'id2': array([atr2_1,atr2_2....atr2_n])}]
```

Please help.

Comment: what code have you tried?

Comment: Related: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/160582/11553

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the csv file in python using the csv module . It will read each line as a list so u will be able to attain your need .

```
import csv 
res_dict = {}
with open(<file name>) as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        key_ = row[0]
        values_ = row[1:]
        res_dict[key] = value

print(res_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have meaningful spaces in the values you are trying to read, you can do the following:

```py
with open("path//to//file", 'r') as f:
    result = {l[0] : l[1:] for l in (d.replace("\n", "").replace(" ", "").split(",") for d in f)}
```

This code parses each line, removes end of lines and spaces, and builds a dictionary using dictionary comprehension.